# undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass on every controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Every time I try to load any page on my local server, I get the following error:

#### Server error

```
[2460faa3017297069fc8b26865c3f95c] [127.0.0.1] 
[2460faa3017297069fc8b26865c3f95c] [127.0.0.1] 
[2460faa3017297069fc8b26865c3f95c] [127.0.0.1] Started GET "/test/social" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-11 19:21:56 -0400
[2460faa3017297069fc8b26865c3f95c] [127.0.0.1] Processing by TestController#social as HTML
[2460faa3017297069fc8b26865c3f95c] [127.0.0.1] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
[2460faa3017297069fc8b26865c3f95c] [127.0.0.1] 
NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/test_controller.rb:4:in `social'
```

#### Test Controller

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def social
    render :layout => false     (line 4)
  end
end
```

#### View

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    HI
  </body>
</html>
```

This error appears for every action, regardless of layout. I tried removing all CSS, JS, and extraneous HTML but the error persists. What is happening here?

Comment: My cows are green. What is happening here?  We need more information!  What do you have in the view (e.g. `social.html.erb`?

Comment: Lol I like green cows! You need to post your entire controller & view code. You're calling `.empty?` somewhere - I presume with `before_action`

Comment: I do not like green cows, I say, I do not like them *any* way. I do not like them in my Rails, I do not like their dumb green tails.

Comment: Added details of green cow potion.